# isInstanceOf for multiple possibilities

Tags: scala, types

I am able to check whether an object o is an instance of A or B like that:

```
o.isInstanceOf[A] || o.isInstanceOf[B]
```

But this gets ugly if i have more possiblities.

Is there a way to define something like this:

```
o.isInstanceOf[A,B,C,D, ...]
```

or

```
o.isInstanceOf(A,B,C,D, ...)
```

or

```
o.isInstanceOf(Set(A,B,C,D, ...))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sealed trait Super
class A extends Super
class B extends Super
class C extends Super
class D extends Super

val unknown: Super = new C
unknown match { case _: A | _: B | _: C => "I'm a super, but not D" } 
// I'm a super, but not D
```

Comment: This only works for `Super` now. I'm looking for a general method for checking such kind of problem that also returns a `Boolean`.

Comment: @Kigyo not quite *only Super*: `def isStrOrInt(x: Any) = x match { case _: String | _: Int => true; case _ => false }`, but yes, there is no way to parameterize this method, so it can generified over Int/String or any other combination unknown ahead of time.

Comment: Feels like a limitation to me. I'd love to see something like this:

Comment: @Kigyo the parser ate your code! Yep, it might be a limitation, but frankly it is **very uncommon** to use so flexible checking. After all the instanceOf chain has to be known ahead of time as well, isn't it?

Comment: Yea. I'm just lazy and like general solutions :). Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Just something that I tried, which failed hard.

```
def isInstance(o : Any, s : Set[Class[_]]) = s.exists(o.getClass == _)

println(isInstance(Nil, Set(Int.getClass, List.getClass))) //false
println(Nil.isInstanceOf[List[_]]) //true

println(isInstance(3, Set(Int.getClass, List.getClass))) //false
println(3.isInstanceOf[Int]) //true
```